# Replace characters of entire string with its unicode (/you...)

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to write function that will replace all chars in variable with its unicode instance for example:

```js
Text = Text.ConvertToUniCode();
```

But the main problem that I'm experiencing is with char that don't include to English language for example:

```
var IllegalChars = ["ə","Ə","ç","Ç","ı","I","ğ","Ğ","ö","Ö","ş","Ş","ü","Ü"];
```

Those who couldn't understand the question:

```
var text= "əkalöğç";
text = ReplaceToUniCode(text); //It will return "\u0259\u018F\u00E7\u00C7\u0131..."
```

PS:I don't use Node.js

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using [punycode.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/#punycodeucs2) (works in Browser and in Node).

```
// punycode works in browser and in Node
var punycode = require('punycode');

function zeros(codepoint) {
  if (codepoint === 0x0000) return '0000';
  if (0x0000 < codepoint && codepoint <= 0x000F) return '000'
  if (0x000F < codepoint && codepoint <= 0x00FF) return '00'
  if (0x0FF < codepoint && codepoint <= 0xFFF) return '0'
  return '';
}

var x = punycode.ucs2.decode('əkalöğç').map(function(codepoint) {
    return '\\u' + zeros(codepoint) + codepoint.toString(16);
}).join('');
console.log(x)
// → "\u0259\u006b\u0061\u006c\u00f6\u011f\u00e7"
```

This works for *all* characters (English, non-English, special characters, emoji).
Note: [`String.prototype.codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) [doesn't work](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) for all characters because of [UCS2 problems](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) – it doesn't work for emoji, and more generally, for so-called "astral codepoints" represented by "surrogate pairs". punycode.js will work for all characters and is trusted (it was originally [bundled](https://nodejs.org/api/punycode.html) in Node.js).

Comment: There's no indication the OP is using node, though.

Comment: Thanks so much sir,i will check your method :)

Comment: could you write the whole workable code please... @James Lawson
Thanks i guess this method is exactly what i want,you saved my day...

Comment: @Cerbrus punycode.js works in the browser and in Node. You made an assumption that this library was Node only.